# What is the core technology of kryo?

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

[Kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/) is really fast and small. what's the secret here?

I have diving into its code for a while, but still need some guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [their page](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo):

> The 2.22 release fixes many reported issues and improves stability and
>   performance. It also introduces a number of new features, most notably
>   that it **can use Unsafe to read and write object memory directly. This
>   is the absolute fastest way to do serialization, especially for large
>   primitive arrays**.

It uses direct bytecode-level access to the fields - `sun.misc.Unsafe` or [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/). Kryo was fast even before introducing unsafe usage. The general answer, I think, is that performance is their highest priority. Java's reflection is not that slow when used carefully - i.e. when the `java.lang.Field` and `java.lang.Method` are cached. I set up an experiment which sorted an array with two different comparators - one was using direct field access and the other was using cached fields. There was only 2x difference, which means unnoticeable in context with IO.

**[FieldSerializer](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#fieldserializer):**

> By default, most classes will end up using `FieldSerializer`. It
>   essentially does what hand written serialization would, but does it
>   automatically. `FieldSerializer` does direct assignment to the object's
>   fields. **If the fields are public, protected, or default access
>   (package private), bytecode generation is used for maximum speed (see
>   ReflectASM). For private fields, setAccessible and cached reflection
>   is used, which is still quite fast.**